# For object of type shared_ptr desructor is called multiple times for a single object created

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I was just writing some small codes in c++11 and i came across a situation where i am not able to understand output. 
For the below code constructor is called only once while destructor is called many times. if i replace **delete[] p** with **delete p** it behaves correctly but why **delete[] p** is giving this kind of output?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class MyClass{
public:
    MyClass(){std::cout<<"Constructor called..."<<std::endl;}
    ~MyClass(){std::cout<<"Destructor called..."<<std::endl;}
    void printMe(){std::cout<<"PrintMe called..."<<std::endl;}
};

int main(){
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> ptr = std::shared_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass(),
    [](MyClass *p){std::cout<<"Custom Deleter ..for p"<<std::endl; delete[] p;});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program has undefined behavior.

You are allocating memory using `new MyClass()` and then deleting it with `delete [] p`.

Use just `delete p;`.

```
int main(){
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> ptr = std::shared_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass(),
    [](MyClass *p){std::cout<<"Custom Deleter ..for p"<<std::endl; delete p;});
}
```

Comment: @R Sahu yes i understand that **delete p** is correct way in this case and **delete [] p** when creating an array of object. It behaves correctly when i create an array of object and do **delete[] p**. But why this particular case is undefined (if at all). is not notion of smart pointer lost if behavior undefined?

Comment: @krishnakumarmandal, `shared_ptr` takes care of maintaining life time of the object. It will make sure that the deleter is called when the life time of the object ends. `shared_ptr` does not (cannot) control how a deleter deletes the object. That means, the deleter has to do the right thing to delete the object.